# Using parameters from a different python file

Tags: python, selenium

I am struggling with how to work with the same parameter between two files. Here is the problem I am having...

I have the locators.py. Note that the fileName here is the parameter declared in a diff file

```
class Locatars(object):
  # Configuration locater
  # note that the fileName here is the parameter declared in a diff file

  FILENAME      = (By.XPATH, //a[contains(@href, '" + fileName + "')])

here is another file called mainPage.py

class mainPage(Page):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super(mainPage, self).__init__(driver)

    def buttonClick(self, fileName):
        self.driver.find_element(Locatars.FILENAME).click()
```

However, when I run the mainPage.py itgives an error and cannot recognize fileName from the locators.py file

Comment: Have you imported 'Locators' in main?

Comment: Yes, I have imported locators, it still says filename not defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Locators file:

```
import locators
```

or

```
from locators import Locators
```

Note that I'm assuming that your two files are in the same directory (or on the Python path).

Comment: Yes, I have imported locators, it still says filename not defined.